# SAML 2.0 TO OAUTH

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, saml-2.0, opensso, wso2-identity-server

I am using an IDP which supports Oauth and SAML BOTH

```
USER ---->SP--Oauth-->IDP--Oauth-->google(oauth2)
```

above flow is working fine where i am logging in to system from google.

now what want to achieve is

```
User ------>SP----oauth--->IDP---SAML--->Another IDP
```

now my question is ...
Is that possible...? if yes please provide me some guide lines how to achieve that.
how can i achieve same thing IDP Initiated flow.
Thanks in advance

Comment: So basically the requirement is to do a OAuth  --> SAML federation????

Comment: Yes, we can say that but I am not sure because  I am new to this

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this? I am currently in need of such an authentication flow.

Comment: Yes it is very easy to achieve through spring authserver . I will provide you more details in some time, Mean while you can try authserver.

Answer (score 0):

You can used other way around like below. It named SAML2Bearer assertion profile, You can found more details here[1].

```
User---->SP----SAML2Bearer--->IDP---Oauth--->Federated IDP
```

[1] http://xacmlinfo.org/2014/10/31/saml2-bearer-assertion-profile-for-oauth-2-0/

Comment: I know, This is possible and I am using it but I have above scenario to achieve. thanks